# How to make text visible in add_traces over the add_shape in plotly python

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I have a plot having rectangles and text. I see that my text in the add_traces is not visible. But when I tried to remove the fill color in add_shape(), I can see the traces.
Here is a sample code:

```
for row in df.index:
    fig.add_shape(type="rect",x0=start, y0=1, x1=start+df[score][row], y1=1.5,line=dict(color='green',),fillcolor='green',)
    start=start+df['score'][row]+2
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=np.cumsum(list(df['score']+2))-df['score'][0],y=[1.25]*df.shape[0],mode="text",textfont=dict(family="sans serif",size=10,color="yellow"),
    text=list(df['Exon_Number']), showlegend=False,textposition='top center',))
```

How do I make the text visible by displaying the traces over the rectangle shape?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own questions hoping it helps anyone in the future.

In the add_shape function, we can send the layer back using layer='below'.
Due to this, the text traces would be visible.

for row in df.index:
fig.add_shape(type="rect",x0=start, y0=1, x1=start+df[score][row], y1=1.5,layer = 'below',line=dict(color='green',),fillcolor='green',)
start=start+df['score'][row]+2
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=np.cumsum(list(df['score']+2))-df['score'][0],y=[1.25]*df.shape[0],mode="text",textfont=dict(family="sans serif",size=10,color="yellow"),
text=list(df['Exon_Number']), showlegend=False,textposition='top center',))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).